# Very Basic Relational Properties

Tags: discrete-mathematics

$R = \{ (1,3),(2,3), (3,4) \}$ 
It says this $R$ is anti-symmetric but how, $a$ does not equal $b$

$R = \{ (1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,4) \}$
It says this is Reflexive (yup) Symmetric (?), Anti-Symmetric (?), and Transitive (?), and I was wondering how this makes sense.

If you draw a graph to represent these I don't know how its true.  Maybe the solutions is messed?

Btw, it's set of relations on the set $A = \{ 1,2,3,4 \}$

Comment: Anti-symmetric just means you can't have both $(a,b)$ and $(b,a)$, right?

Comment: No, it's if u have both (a,b)and(b,a) then => a=b

Comment: OK, then what's the difficulty? There are no $a$ and $b$ such that $R$ has both $(a,b)$ and $(b,a)$, so the "then" part never eventuates, right?

Comment: Hey you are right! Sorry!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** Now that you have changed the first problem, it is actually anti-symmetric. Why? Because being anti-symmetric means obeying an if-statement that says **if** you have $(x,y)$ and $(y,x)$, **then** $x = y$. Here, you don't have anything satisfying the if part of this conditional; thus, we say the if-then statement (vacuously) holds.

As for the second example, this is certainly symmetric and transitive: both of those properties are if-then statements, and here the "if" part can only be satisfied by ordered pairs of the form $(n,n)$. In fact, this relation is a formal way of writing what we would normally represent with "$=$", that is, equality in the standard sense of arithmetic, which you probably know is an equivalence relation.

Thinking of the second relation as equality, hopefully you can see why anti-symmetry holds too, though it does so in a somewhat vacuous manner (as in the first example).

Comment: Sorry, check my edit for the first example, I wrote down the wrong question

Comment: Wait I'm not sure I understood that. So if there is no (a,b)and(b,a) in a relation it's always anti symmetric? That is really vague

Comment: In general, given a statement of the form "if P, then Q", we say it's false only when P is satisfied but Q is not. If P is not satisfied, then we don't really care about Q; we just say the statement is true. (In such a scenario, one might say it's "vacuously" true.) That's what's happening here: you have if-then statements where the if part is not satisfied, so the then part isn't important. [Hopefully this all sounds familiar and you aren't seeing it here for the first time!]

Comment: Yea I understand because in logic if you have p 0 it's always true regardless the value of Q. My real question is then in every relation there is no (a,b)and(b,a) is it always antisymmetric

Comment: Yes, if for every (a,b) you *don't* have (b,a), then the relation is antisymmetric. Note: if for every (a,b) you *do* have (b,a), then the relation is symmetric! Hopefully you can now see how the word "antisymmetric" arises.

Comment: OK THANK U MATH GOD ^_^

Comment: Hey, I have one more question, is (2,3),(3,2) is this transivitive.